# How should special terms be styled according to the IEEE style guide?

Tags: writing-style, ieee

I was wondering how to style *special terms* (such as *private key*), according to IEEE Style Manual.
I couldn't find any meaningful source nor any stack exchange discussion.
In my opinion one of these should apply:

- latex emph or italic font face (as used in the style manual itself)
- single quotes (Latex ` ')
- double quotes (Latex ``, '', or ")

Is any of these required or preferred?

Answer (score 2):

You can see IEEE's style guide [here](http://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/IEEE-Editorial-Style-Manual-for-Authors.pdf); however, it does not state a policy for "special terms." It does contain many examples, all of which show common technical words used with no quotes or italics. Looking through some published IEEE papers, I again see no examples of technical words being introduced with italics or quotation marks. This is aligned with my intuition: using italics or quotes for common technical terms (like private key) might be natural in a textbook but less so in a research paper. Indeed, your example of "private key" is such a widely-used term that it is probably not necessary to supply a definition at all (though this may vary depending on your target audience).